# Replace/delete field using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, replace, sqlalchemy

Using postgres in python,

1. How do I replace all fields from the same column that match a specified value? For example, let's say I want to replace any fields that match "green" with "red" in the "Color" column.
2. How to delete all fields from the same column  that match a specified value? For example, I'm trying to deleted all fields that match "green" in the Color column.

Answer (score 9):

Ad1. You need something like this:

```
session.query(Foo).filter_by(color = 'green').update({ 'color': 'red' })
session.commit()
```

Ad2. Similarly:

```
session.query(Foo).filter_by(color = 'green').delete()
session.commit()
```

You can find the querying documentation [here](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/orm/query.html) and [here](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html#querying).

Comment: I think the second answer deletes the entire row.  I actually only want to delete the field.

Comment: I tried to use something like this to make field empty but it not seem to work: session.query(Foo).filter_by(color = 'green').update({ 'color': '' })

Comment: `session.query(Foo).filter_by(color = 'green').update({ 'color': '' })` should work just fine. Maybe you didn't commit? Anyway, creating the engine with `echo = True` (or configuring `sqlalchemy.engine` logger) should help you debug that.